# New to wxWidgets and GUI in general - learning materials ? ( wxWidgets 3.0, C++, Win 7, CodeBlocks )

Tags: c++, windows-7, wxwidgets, codeblocks

I would like to know about learning resources for the new major wxWidgets 3.0 release. I see there are many resources online for older versions, as well as a book from 2005. But I am not sure they would be a good fit. Web tutorials would be best, but anything is welcome.

As stated, I am completely new to GUI programming. I am planning to use CodeBlocks with C++, on a Win 7, 64 bit machine. Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand, the differences between 2.9.x and 3.0 would likely not make as much difference as you might think, especially if you are completely new to GUI programming.  The vast majority of older  wxWidgets tutorials and online information will still apply.  Also, they have excellent online API documentation and included examples that you can tear apart.  My advice would be to just download it, start compiling examples, and read any tutorials that look interesting.  Best of luck!  :-)

Comment: So if I find some 2.9.x tutorials, they will be helpful also for 3.0, and not confusing ? As a beginner, I must be very careful about the selection. Thank you =)

Comment: I would say yes.  I have been developing with wx for 4 years, but I haven't switched to 3.0 yet since it just came out.  That's why this is a comment, not an answer...  :-)

Comment: I understand. I see the html documentation, and it looks like like wx got vast and full of features ! I really hope there will be some good book / manual out soon, it would help a great deal. Where do you usually go for support, like a forum... ?

Comment: I usually use Google and the wxWidgets API documentation. [(link)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/)  I used to like books, too, but then I found that books are almost always at least a version behind, whereas the online documentation stays pretty much on target.  Also, remember "Nothing teaches like the game!"  Dive into the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these resources:

http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/

http://hosannahighertech.co.tz/forums/showthread.php?tid=60

Sad thing is that there aren't many recent complete books about wxWidgets.